# Spring security default configuration always throws 401

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-security

I'm creating a new Spring REST application with some basic services and entities.

I added Spring Security and without overriding any class, i just added to application.properties a user and password.

So far so good, i opened Postman to try out a endpoint and it always return 401 to my requests.

I tried in postman set the authorization via "Basic Auth" (is what header WWW-Authenticate asks), tried "Digest auth" using the "Realm" value from the header. But none of it works.

---

Here is what i have in my **application.properties**

```xml
spring.security.user.name=root
spring.security.user.password=root
```

This is my request

https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ezND.jpg

*(Sorry i can't embbed the image because of my reputation)*

And here is the endpoint

```java
@PostMapping("saveUsuario")
public Usuario saveUsuario(Usuario usuario) {
        return usuarioRepository.save(usuario);
}
```

(If possible) i don't want to override any Spring Security class, just "use as it".

Thank you!

Comment: You should be able to do your use case without a custom Spring Security class. In fact, nothing appears to be wrong at first blush. Please compare your application to this hello world sample - https://github.com/jzheaux/hello-security - and let me know what you think.

Comment: Thanks for the repo! So i checked it out. Using @GetMapping it works flawlessly. When using PostMapping it keep returning an 401.

Lately, it just return "Forbidden" (probably mistake in url or something like that)

Comment: I just created a pull request with the change i said to your repo!

Comment: Ah, thank you for the PR, I had misunderstood. Spring Security automatically adds CSRF defense through a token. For this, you will, indeed, need a simple extension of `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`, where you can configure the CSRF defense mechanism - https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#when-to-use-csrf-protection

Comment: Adding support to CSRF fixed the problem! Thanks

But one last thing: It also let me call any endpoints without authentication which isn't very nice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So here is what i found.

Thanks to @jzheaux we discover that the problem was with the csrf configuration (Using POST request).

So i was forced to override the class **WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter** to disable it.

```java
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {


    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable();
    }
}
```

But then, the endpoints could be called without authentication!

So, this is the final code:

```java
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable();
        http.cors();
        http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().fullyAuthenticated();
        http.httpBasic();
        http.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.NEVER);
    }
}
```

- First disable the CSRF.
- Then enable Cors.
- I set that i want any request to be fully authenticated
- The challenge type is HTTP basic
- I disable the creation of cookies so it'll always ask for credentials.

So far so good, it's working!

Answer (score -1):

Per https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.5.0.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-security

you should change your password with

`security.user.password=root`

instead of `spring.security.user.password=root`

similar security properties that are overridable are in the @ConfigurationProperties class: SecurityProperties.java

See https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/v1.5.0.RELEASE/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/security/SecurityProperties.java

Comment: Yes! I know that i can (and i should) change the password. The problem is, that any credential returns 401.

Comment: @IvánPagano sorry if it was misunderstood what I was implying. I was stating that the property you were using to force password change was had an extra work on prefix. I was not commenting on your password.    Updated original answer

Comment: That annotation is deprecated, according to Intellij IDEA (https://imgur.com/VTdHLkN)