# Spring Boot: Only Postman “GET” requests allowed when using Spring Boot but not “POST”, “PUT” or “DELETE”; they yield an “401 Unauthorized” error

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, authorization

I am new to `Spring Boot` and right now, I am building an application according to [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3idkW2fkXKA&t=9m38s). My code looks as follows.

---

## Code snippets

### `pom.xml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"
      encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.6</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.pokemonreview</groupId>
    <artifactId>api</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>api</name>
    <description>Pokemon Review API Course 2022</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.rungroop</groupId>
            <artifactId>web</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

---

### `application.properties` file (the simple passwords are no secret and just used for testing purposes):

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/pokemonApiCourse
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=postgres
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.security.user.name=test
spring.security.user.password=test
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
```

---

### Model:

```
package com.pokemonreview.api.models;

import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
import jakarta.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import jakarta.persistence.GenerationType;
import jakarta.persistence.Id;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
public class PokemonEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private String type;
}
```

---

### Controller:

```
package com.pokemonreview.api.controllers;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.DeleteMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PutMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseStatus;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.pokemonreview.api.models.PokemonEntity;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/")
public class PokemonController {
    @GetMapping("pokemon")
    public ResponseEntity<List<PokemonEntity>> getPokemons() {
        List<PokemonEntity> pokemonEntities = new ArrayList<PokemonEntity>();
        pokemonEntities.add(new PokemonEntity(1L, "Squirtle", "Water"));
        pokemonEntities.add(new PokemonEntity(2L, "Pikachu", "Electric"));
        pokemonEntities.add(new PokemonEntity(3L, "Charmander", "Fire"));
        return ResponseEntity.ok(pokemonEntities);
    }
    
    @GetMapping("pokemon/{id}")
    public PokemonEntity pokemonDetail(@PathVariable Long id) {
        return new PokemonEntity(id, "Squirtle", "Water");
    }
    
    @PostMapping("pokemon/create")
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
    public ResponseEntity<PokemonEntity> createPokemon(@RequestBody PokemonEntity pokemonEntity) {
        System.out.println(pokemonEntity.getName());
        System.out.println(pokemonEntity.getType());
        return new ResponseEntity<PokemonEntity>(pokemonEntity, HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }
    
    @PutMapping("pokemon/{id}/update")
    public ResponseEntity<PokemonEntity> updatePokemon(@RequestBody PokemonEntity pokemonEntity,
                                                       @PathVariable("id") Long id) {
        System.out.println(pokemonEntity.getName());
        System.out.println(pokemonEntity.getType());
        return ResponseEntity.ok(pokemonEntity);
    }
    
    @DeleteMapping("pokemon/{id}/delete")
    public ResponseEntity<String> deletePokemon(@PathVariable("id") Long id) {
        System.out.println(id);
        return ResponseEntity.ok("Pokemon deleted successfully");
    }
}
```

---

### Modifications I have made

Please note that …

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.6</version>
</dependency>
```

… was added by me to the `pom.xml` file but it does *not* make a difference if it is there or not. An authentication is *always* required – *no matter* if the `Spring Security` dependency is added or not! (Why is that? In the tutorial, *no* authorisation is required!) – and if I do not add the two lines …

```
spring.security.user.name=test
spring.security.user.password=test
```

… to the `application.properties` file, a password for the user `user` is generated every time I start up the `Spring Boot` application.

Also, my `id` variable is not an `int`, as demonstrated in the tutorial, but a `Long`.

Furthermore, please note that `javax.persistence` packages are used in the tutorial. The only packages that are suggested to me are `jakarta.persistence` packages.

---

## `Postman` problems: Only `GET` requests are allowed

I am using `Postman` in order to test `GET`, `POST`, `PUT` and `DELETE` requests but only `GET` requests work. *Every time*, the options in my `Authorization` tab are set as follows:

- **`Type:`** `Basic Auth`

  - **`Username:`** `test`
  - **`Password:`** `test`

### Working `GET` requests

The first `GET` request on `http://localhost:8080/api/pokemon` yields the following result:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Squirtle",
        "type": "Water"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Pikachu",
        "type": "Electric"
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "Charmander",
        "type": "Fire"
    }
]
```

The result of the second `GET` request on `http://localhost:8080/api/pokemon/5` is as follows:

```
{
    "id": 5,
    "name": "Squirtle",
    "type": "Water"
}
```

### Failing `POST`, `PUT` and `DELETE` requests

The `POST` request is conducted on `http://localhost:8080/api/pokemon/create` and in the `Body` tab, `raw` and `JSON` are selected and the following is inserted:

```
{
    "name": "Pidgey",
    "type": "Earth"
}
```

If I now click on <kbd>`Send`</kbd>, nothing is returned and the status `401 Unauthorized` is displayed.

The `PUT` (`http://localhost:8080/api/pokemon/5/update`) and `DELETE` (`http://localhost:8080/api/pokemon/5/delete`) requests yield the same results.

What is wrong? In the tutorial, everything works just fine and I already tried tweaking the `pom.xml` and `application.properties` files in many ways according to the solutions I found on the internet but all of this has not solved my problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spring security default configuration always throws 401](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55812923/spring-security-default-configuration-always-throws-401)

Answer (score -1):

I finally found out what the problem was. `Spring Security` was not configured properly. When I added the following package and class, everything started to work just fine:

```
package com.pokemonreview.api.security;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {   
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {        
        httpSecurity.csrf()
                    .disable()
                    .authorizeHttpRequests()
                    .requestMatchers("/api/pokemon/**")
                    .permitAll();
        return httpSecurity.build();
    }
}
```

Comment: It was probably related to CSRF. Take a look at https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/exploits/csrf.html